# Localizing attached properties in XAML/WinRT

Tags: windows, xaml, localization, windows-runtime

I'm attempting to localize my WinRT app. I don't need anything too fancy, so I've been using x:Uid on XAML elements in conjunction with resource files that have properties such as "PageTitleTextBox.Text" set. This method was working great until I ran into an issue with attached properties.

I've defined a few app bar buttons using similar markup to what I've seen in other examples:

```
<Button x:Name="AddFolderButton" Click="AddFolderButton_Tapped" x:Uid="FoldersPageAppBarAddFolderButton" AutomationProperties.Name="Test" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>&#xE109;</Button.Content>
</Button >
```

In this case, I'd like to localize AddFolderButton's label, currently defined by `AutomationProperties.Name`. I tried setting a key in my resource file to `FoldersPageAppBarAddFolderButton.AutomationProperties.Name`, but this fails on runtime.

Is it possible to localize this label using XAML, or do I need to do this programatically in the code-behind file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to handle attached properties a bit differently, i.e. their namespace must be included in the reource key like this:

```
FoldersPageAppBarAddFolderButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx).